# Priority Queue using MultiMap - Java

Tags: java, priority-queue, guava, multimap

I have to implement Priority Queue using MultiMap. I use MultiMap from Google Collections. 
The following code creates a MultiMap and adds few elements into it.

```
    Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = HashMultimap.create();

    multimap.put(5,"example");
    multimap.put(1,"is");
    multimap.put(1,"this");
    multimap.put(4,"some");
```

Now my problem is how to write the pop method?

I think that there should be a for loop and it should be iterating through MultiMap.

The lowest key should be the highest priority, so in C++ I would set a pointer to the first element and increment it. How to do it in Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `HashMultimap` you're using won't give you any help in efficiently selecting the lowest element. Instead use a `TreeMultimap` (also in Google Collections) which lets you specify an ordering and iterate through the items in the list in that order. For instance:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : multimap.entries()) {
  System.out.println("Item " + entry.getValue() + " has priority " + entry.getKey();
}
```

You'll notice that this always prints out entries in priority order, so to get the first-priority element you can just do `multimap.entries().iterator().next()`  (assuming you know the map has at least one element).

See [the TreeMultimap documentation](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that's usefull, but how to iterate through TreeMultiMap?

Comment: Use `multimap.entries()` and iterate through that using its `iterator()` method. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I think it would be last question: I can display the object by: `System.out.println(multimap.entries().iterator().next());` and now how to remove this first-priority element (like pop method usually does)?

Comment: Easiest way would be to just use `multimap.remove(key, value)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers jacobm. I finally finished it.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly that you're using Multimap as the internals for your own PriorityQueue class, rather than just trying to use Multimap as a priority queue, then you should probably keep a SortedSet (I'll call it sortedKeys) of all the keys.  Then you can use
`multimap.get(sortedKeys.first())` to pop the first element.

By "keeping a SortedSet", I mean that each time you add something to your Multimap, add its key to a SortedSet.  When you remove items from your Multimap, remove their keys from the SortedSet.  The goal being that your SortedSet stays equal to Multimap.keySet(), but without the overhead of calling `SortedSet.clear(); SortedSet.addAll(...)` all the time.

The alternative is going to be creating a SortedSet each time which would be much slower.  It may help you understand what I'm saying though:

```
public Collection<V> pop() {
    SortedSet keys = new TreeSet(multimap.keySet());
    return multimap.get(keys.first());
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i have to use MultiMap in this project :/

Comment: jacobm's answer is simpler since the TreeMultimap already does all this for you.  I'm not that familiar with google collections so I didn't realize they already had a class that did this.

Comment: Can SortedSet contain two or more same keys, as could happen in MultiMap?

Comment: Sets don't have "keys", they just have elements, and yes you can have duplicate elements.

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply use the [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) class in the JDK?

With the TreeMultimap approach jacobm suggested, the following code is more concise.

```
Iterator<String> iterator = multimap.values().iterator();
String value = iterator.next();
iterator.remove();
```